# Strip Typescript decorator in release build

Tags: typescript, webpack, decorator, uglifyjs

I have debug-time Typescript [decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) `@log`, which logs input/output/stats of the decorated functions.

I'd like to totally strip this particular `@log` decorator when compiling release version.

It is easy to remove console.log statements from the release build or do things conditionally in the decorator code, but I would like to make sure there's no overhead with calling decorator function itself.

Is there any way this can be achieved with Typescript?

My project is webpack-based. If this is not possible with Typescript, maybe this can be done at later stage with Babel plugin, with UglifyJS or some other alternative plugin?

Comment: you might be able to store your decorator in its own file / module, then for a release build use an alias for that path / module-name that resolves to a no-op function instead. However, that does keep the decorator so its not really answering your question.

Comment: could possibly also be done via a typescript transformer plugin that explicitly strips out the decorator code entirely: see https://github.com/cevek/ttypescript

Comment: Actually, I started from your pointers and realized that I totally missed it how *Decorator Factory* works :). It appears, if I simply return "undefined" in the factory, then the target function is not decorated at all. I'll test it a bit more, and if it indeed works like that - it would be acceptable. I can simply check for "DEBUG" var in the factory. There's tiny loading time overhead (calling __decorate internal func when JS is first evaluated). But object instantiation and calls appear to be "free"!

Comment: @sbat did you find anything in the end? I don't like having this overhead too.

Comment: @LppEdd in my own accepted answer I've explained that there is no runtime overhead during the _call_ itself. Only at the initialization time. This was ok for my usecase.

Comment: @sbat sure, I understood that. However I would really want to strip some unneeded marker decorators. It's dead code. Did you have a look at the Transformer API?

Comment: @LppEdd nope. :( I would have probably checked if Babel decorator implementation provides needed functionality (and if TS can keep decorators "as is" when emitting ES2016 output), or if I can do something as part of webpack build process.

Comment: @sbat see my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57697892/typescript-transformer-decorator-isnt-completely-removed-from-ast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This compile-time Transformer removes Decorators from elements and from named imports.
I'll keep the code updated, as it's just a (working) test.

```
export default (decorators: string[]) => {
  const importDeclarationsToRemove = [] as ts.ImportDeclaration[];

  const updateNamedImports = (node: ts.NamedImports) => {
    const newElements = node.elements.filter(v => !decorators.includes(v.name.getText()));

    if (newElements.length > 0) {
      ts.updateNamedImports(node, newElements);
    } else {
      importDeclarationsToRemove.push(node.parent.parent);
    }
  };

  const createVisitor = (
    context: ts.TransformationContext
  ): ((node: ts.Node) => ts.VisitResult<ts.Node>) => {
    const visitor: ts.Visitor = (node: ts.Node): ts.VisitResult<any> => {
      // Remove Decorators from imports
      if (ts.isNamedImports(node)) {
        updateNamedImports(node);
      }

      // Remove Decorators applied to elements
      if (ts.isDecorator(node)) {
        const decorator = node as ts.Decorator;
        const identifier = decorator.getChildAt(1) as ts.Identifier;

        if (decorators.includes(identifier.getText())) {
          return undefined;
        }
      }

      const resultNode = ts.visitEachChild(node, visitor, context);
      const index = importDeclarationsToRemove.findIndex(id => id === resultNode);

      if (index !== -1) {
        importDeclarationsToRemove.splice(index, 1);
        return undefined;
      }

      return resultNode;
    };

    return visitor;
  };

  return (context: ts.TransformationContext) => (sourceFile: ts.SourceFile) =>
    sourceFile.fileName.endsWith('component.ts')
      ? ts.visitNode(sourceFile, createVisitor(context))
      : sourceFile;
};
```

---

```
program.emit(
  program.getSourceFile('test.component.ts'),
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  {
    before: [stripDecorators(['Stateful', 'StatefulTwo', 'StatefulThree'])]
  }
);
```

Input:

```
import { Stateful, StatefulThree, StatefulTwo } from './decorators';

@Stateful
@StatefulTwo
@StatefulThree
export class Example {
  private str = '';

  getStr(): string {
    return this.str;
  }
}
```

JS output:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
class Example {
    constructor() {
        this.str = '';
    }
    getStr() {
        return this.str;
    }
}
exports.Example = Example;
```

Comment: I haven't tested/reviewed in details, but it looks like this exactly addresses my old original question! Thanks for looking into the Transformer approach!

Comment: @sbat It's nothing. I'm still learning how to do this. Keep in mind you still cannot use transformers with pure `tsc`. I've posted a comment on the TS Plan here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33118

Answer (score 2):

When asking this question, I totally overlooked one embarrassingly trivial aspect. Decorator function itself is only invoked once per method declaration. If decorator is evaluated at initialization time to no-op function, overhead will only occur at initialization time and it will be pretty minimal as demonstrated in the code below.

Class instantiation and runtime function calls to the functions, marked with the `@log` decorator, will be free from any overhead.

```
const DEBUG = false;

const logDebug = function(_target: any, key: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): any {
    console.log("log(): called");

    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) {
        const functionName = key;
        console.log(functionName + "(" + args.join(", ") + ")");
        const result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        console.log("=> " + result);
        return result;
    };
    return descriptor;
};
const logNoop = function() {};
const log = DEBUG ? logDebug : logNoop;

class Test {
    @log
    test(a: number, b: number) {
        console.log("test(): called", a, b);
    }
}

new Test().test(1, 2);
new Test().test(3, 5);
```

Fragment of the compiled JS to show that overhead is indeed minimal:

```
var Test = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Test() {
    }
    Test.prototype.test = function (a, b) {
        console.log("test(): called", a, b);
    };
    __decorate([
        log
    ], Test.prototype, "test", null);
    return Test;
}());
```

Comment: I'm marking this as accepted answer. However, please do provide an answer if there's a practical way to remove even this minimal overhead (i.e. __decorate call at loading time).