# TypeScript Transformer - decorator isn't completely removed from AST

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I'm trying to remove a specific *Decorator* from the AST of certain source files.
I was able to lookup the Decorator `Node`s, however the emitted code still contains a call to the `__decorate([...])` function.

Following is the Transformer, with its `Visitor`.

```
export default function() {
  function createVisitor(
    ctx: ts.TransformationContext,
    sourceFile: ts.SourceFile
  ): (node: ts.Node) => ts.VisitResult<ts.Node> {
    const visitor: ts.Visitor = (node: ts.Node): ts.VisitResult<any> => {
      if (ts.isDecorator(node)) {
        if (node.getText(sourceFile) === '@Stateful') {
          return undefined;
        }
      }

      return ts.visitEachChild(node, visitor, ctx);
    };

    return visitor;
  }

  return (ctx: ts.TransformationContext) => (sourceFile: ts.SourceFile) =>
    sourceFile.fileName.endsWith('component.ts')
      ? ts.visitNode(sourceFile, createVisitor(ctx, sourceFile))
      : sourceFile;
}
```

As you can see, I intercept `@Stateful` decorator `Node`s

```
if (ts.isDecorator(node)) {
  if (node.getText(sourceFile) === '@Stateful') {
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

And I remove that AST `Node` by returning `undefined`.
However the compiled code still uses the `__decorate` function, though with an empty array

```
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    ...
};
import { Stateful } from './test.decorator';
export class Example {
    constructor() {
        this.str = '';
    }
    getStr() {
        return this.str;
    }
}
Example = __decorate([], Example);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Really weird... when I log the parent node in the console it has a `decorators` property showing one item, but when I call `.length` on the array or try to index into it, it will have zero items & be undefined. Seems like a bug. As a workaround, you may have luck by setting the parent's `decorator` property to undefined.

Comment: @DavidSherret hey! Thanks. I did try that too, same result. I have no idea, really. I appreciate your interest btw

Comment: @DavidSherret it was TS 3.5.3. Updating to 3.6.2 solved this!
Also, I'm using your TypeScript AST viewer, thank you very much ;)

Comment: nice! That was perfect timing :) Also, I’m glad the site has been useful for you!

Comment: @DavidSherret btw, do you happen to know if TSC will support transformers in a better way in future releases? Currently they cannot even be used via command line. I will ask on Gitter too.

Comment: I hope so! It was mentioned in the [TS 3.4 iteration plan](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30281), but I have yet to see it since.

Comment: @DavidSherret thanks. I've added a comment on the Roadmap https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33118